# How to find which application created each c3p0 connection pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jdbc, c3p0

In Tomcat, I have a shared c3p0 jar placed in Tomcat's lib folder with three different applications using it.

Is there a way to identify which application created which connection pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy thing to do is to use c3p0's [named configurations](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#named_configurations) to define a distinct configuration for each application, and let each application construct its own pool. The `dataSourceName` parameter will let you permanently discriminate between your DataSources, e.g. in a JMX MBean client.